# how to set video path programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

In my project there are one video tag and two buttons. I am trying to do that when I click button1 then video starts playing and when I will click another button then another video starts playing. These two videos are in video folder inside my project.

here is the test.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <video  id="videoplr" width="500" controls="controls" runat="server"></video>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind c# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoplr.Attributes["src"] = "C:\\Users\\Punam\\Desktop\\Project\\videos\\personal_talk.MP4";
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoplr.Attributes["src"] = "C:\\Users\\Punam\\Desktop\\Project\\videos\\Tags.MP4";
    }
}
```

When I am clicking buttons then video is not playing. I am new bie in asp.net.

Comment: The path needs to be a Url, not a local file path.  For example, if the videos are in your project folder, in a subfolder called "videos" then you would set the src attribute to "/videos/personal_talk.MP4" (for example)

Comment: single slash or double slash?

Comment: Forward slashes can be single in strings.  Backslashes need to be double, unless you decorate the string with an @ - `"C:\\Folder\\File"` == `@"C:\Folder\File"`

Comment: yooo...got it...works fine